# Android get multiple resource name (<color name="c1">@color/c2</color>)

Tags: android, android-resources

I am using a skin frame, I need to get the resource name.
When I use associated resources, I can't get it right resources name, like this:

```xml
    <color name="color_skin">#ffff0000</color>
    <color name="color_login">@color/color_skin</color>
```

```java
String resName = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.color_login);
resName is "color_login"
```

I want get resName is "color_skin", How can I do it?

**Additional instructions**
([SkinUtils](https://github.com/ximsfei/Android-skin-support) Use correctly in xml)
SkinUtils for xml:

```xml
<com.test.TestView
    ...
    android:background="@color/color_login"/>

<declare-styleable name="SkinBackgroundHelper"><attr name="android:background"/></declare-styleable>
```

SkinUtils for java code:

```java
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SkinBackgroundHelper, defStyleAttr, 0);
    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.SkinBackgroundHelper_android_background)) {
        int resourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.SkinBackgroundHelper_android_background, 0);
        // resourceId is R.id.color_skin !!!
    }
```

SkinUtils in xml, get final resourceId is "R.id.color_skin".
If only java code, I can't get "R.id.color_skin" for "R.idcolor_login".

Comment: I don't find any reason to return it "color_skin"

Comment: @PankajKumar My Apk have R.id.color_skin and R.id.color_login resource.My skin only have R.id.color_skin.Now change color is successful for xml, but failure for java code, Because I didn't find "color_login" in my skin. If there is this way, I want to use it. If not, I can do it by copying it...